# replace a symbol in the same line of multistring

Tags: python

I am doing a python project, its a review maker kind using a sample string and replacing the symbol in the same line of the multistring then printing it with (check mark) next to the same text in the string as user input , I have a problem in replacing a certain symbol (☑) with the same line of string which equal to user input.
Here is a code example to get the idea:

```
 import string
 import re

    #this is a review  maker with check boxes
    Graphics = """
    ☐ You forget what reality is,
    ☐ Beautiful,
    ☐ Good,
    ☐ Decent,
    ☐ Bad,
    ☐ Don't look too long at it,
    ☐ MS-DOS
    """
    def findAndReplace(Graphics):
      find_symbol = re.search(symbol = "☐")
      new_symbol =re.replace(symbol1 = "☑")
    return new_symbol

     # ask question to the user and replace symbol to same answer of the user.

    print = "Choose an answer each question to write the review"
    # the strings down is equal to the Graphics strings
    print = " Beautiful - Good - Decent - Bad"

      #control flow

    user_input1 = input("what do you think about Graphics? ")
    if  user_input1 in Graphics:
       findAndReplace(Graphics)
    print(Graphics)
    else:
       print("we still have errors -")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something on the lines of :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import string
import re

#this is a review  maker with check boxes
Graphics = """
☐ You forget what reality is,
☐ Beautiful,
☐ Good,
☐ Decent,
☐ Bad,
☐ Don't look too long at it,
☐ MS-DOS
"""
def findAndReplace(line, line_num):
   replacement_string = re.sub("☐", "☑", line)
   mylist[line_num] = replacement_string
   return "\n".join(mylist)

# ask question to the user and replace symbol to same answer of the user.

print( "Choose an answer each question to write the review")
# the strings down is equal to the Graphics strings
print(" Beautiful - Good - Decent - Bad")

#control flow

mylist = Graphics.split('\n')
user_input1 = input("what do you think about Graphics? ")
for i, line in enumerate(mylist):
   try:
       if  user_input1 in line:
           Graphics = findAndReplace(line, i)
           print(Graphics)
   except:
       print("we still have errors -")
```

Another perhaps better method leveraging regular expressions is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import string
import re

#this is a review  maker with check boxes
Graphics = """
☐ You forget what reality is,
☐ Beautiful,
☐ Good,
☐ Decent,
☐ Bad,
☐ Don't look too long at it,
☐ MS-DOS
"""

# ask question to the user and replace symbol to same answer of the user.

print( "Choose an answer each question to write the review")
# the strings down is equal to the Graphics strings
print(" Beautiful - Good - Decent - Bad")


#control flow

user_input1 = input("what do you think about Graphics? ")

try:
    result = re.search(user_input1, Graphics)

    first = Graphics[:result.start()]
    last = Graphics[result.start():]

    start = first.rfind("☐")

    new_string = first[:start] + first[start:].replace("☐", "☑")

    Graphics = new_string + last

    print(Graphics)
except:
    print("we still have errors -")
```

Comment: yeah but i still have error with **(TypeError: 'str' object is not callable)** , and when i write Good , it doesnt match and print!

Comment: @jessicaalison: Can you tell me where do you, get this error on which line, and what input are you giving?

Comment: well i fixed this issue but when i put input Good , it comes with nothing , like doesnt print the list back with the Mark sybmol , its just ending the input with nothing

Comment: @jessicaalison: I have tried the code at my end, I ended up getting the **Mark** symbol for `"Good"`. Can you try copying the code exactly in a python script and running it. Also, you might be interested in the second method, I just added in the edit.

Comment: Thank you , i had a bug, just another quick question , if i have more variables as Graphics , how can i make it as funtion for any variable  ?

Comment: @jessicaalison: In the `regex` example (which is simpler), just create a function (say) `def marker(user_input_1, unmarked_string):` and put the code from the `try except` block inside it, replacing `Graphics` with `unmarked_string`. You can have various strings such as **Graphics**, either in the `.py` file or as an *input* or it can be read from a `.txt` file

Comment: i was thinking about this as well , thank you <3